# В чём разница между Gradle и Maven?

Tags: maven, gradle

Что лучше Maven или Gradle? В чем их разница?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что одинаково:

- оба являются инструментами для внедрения зависимостей, построения проектов, автоматизации сборки проектов.

Отличия:

- По разному конфигурируются: Мавен использует обычную XML, Gradle использует domain-specific language (DSL) основанный на Groovy или Котлине.
  Плюсы ХМЛ - намного проще в освоении. Плюсы DSL - более жирный синтаксис и более гибкая вещь, чем ХМЛ.
  Соответственно, можно сделать вывод (это мой личный и дискусионный). Что в таком случае Maven больше подойдет для мелких проектов. А Гредл для более крупных проектов. (Гредл более оптимизированный и работает быстрее)
- Мавен старее чем Гредл. То есть сейчас стараются использовать Гредл, но уже написано киллометры проектов, используя Мавен, и эти приложения до сих пор живут и их поддерживают.

Итог: невозможно сказать что лучше. У каждого инструмента свои + и -. Но по моему мнению, Мавен лучше подойдет для начинающих с их небольшими проектами. Так как в учебных проектах не удастся прочувствовать всех преймуществ Гредла, а время на изучения вы потратите больше.

Comment: если не сложно дополните ответ, про то что градл написан на мейвене и использует его репозитории и если кто то захочет писать свою библиотеку ему прийдется выгружать ее на мейвен чтобы она работала в гредле не знаю правда это или нет просто прочитал в интеренете)

Comment: Не совсем: Гредл не написан на Мавен. Для внедрения зависимостей и Мавен и Грэдл используют по дефолту центральный репозиторий Мавен. (Вы это можете изменить на свой, например, или например на внутренний репозиторий компании, в которой работаете). Можете вообще никуда не публиковать свою библиотеку. Можете хранить и ее и использовать локально со своего компа. Но это больше для тестирования и учебных проектов. Смысл библиотеки чтобы ее использовать в разных проектах - поэтому, в боевых условиях, ее все таки нужно публиковать